# Proving that the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $(a, 1/a^2)$ intersects $f$ at one other point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This comes from Spivak's *Calculus* (problem 2b from chapter 9).  Here, $f(x)=1/x^2$.

My approach was as follows:

I took $f'$ and wrote down the tangent line to $f$ at $(a, 1/a^2)$, namely $y_a=-2/a^3(x-a)+1/a^2$.  Reasoning that the intersections between $f$ and $y_a$ would correspond to the zeros of $f-y_a$, I proceeded to write down $f-y_a$.  However, when I rearranged $f-y_a=1/x^2+2x/a^3-3/a^2$ to $2x^3/a^3-3x^2/a^2+1$, I became very puzzled, since this turned out to be cubic--and cannot have only two zeros (and so, in particular, $y_a$ would not intersect the original graph in only two places, namely in $(a, 1/a)$ and some other point)--where I was expecting a quadratic.  Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Things are turning out as they should. There is a *double root* at $x=a$.  By the way, the third root can be found with minimal calculation, from either the known sum or the  known product of the roots.